# To display all records of table?

Tags: sql, oracle

To display all records of table1 except A containing  2 as well as B containing 5

```
Table1
------

A          B
-         
8          5

2          9

null       4

2          5
```

```
select * from table1 where a not in 2 and b not in 5;
```

It doesn't work ,It will display like 0 rows selected

Comment: *as well as* means `AND` or `OR` ?

Comment: select * from table1 except (select * from table1 where a= 2 or b= 5);  ====== OR ========== select * from table1 where a != 2 or b != 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE (a is null or a != 2) and (b is null or b != 5)
```

**EDIT**

[Sql Fiddle, many thanks to Nagaraj S](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5584b/14)

Comment: @NagarajS: Thanks, I add your fiddle in my answer ;)